# How to perform action when navigation controller pops a view on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

I want to do some saving stuff when the user hits the back button on a navigation controller.  Is this only possible by implementing

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    int index = [[self.navigationController.viewControllers] indexOfObject:[self.navigationController.visibleViewController]];
    if(viewController == [[self.navigationController.viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index-1])
        //saving code here
```

so the delegate gets called when it's about to show the previous view controller.  Is there a more elegant way of knowing when the view controller will be popped?

and I can't use viewWillDisappear because there's a button that displays a UIImagePickerController, and I don't want the saving to be done then.  Any thoughts?

Comment: well you write the code for when a view controller get's popped, so you could do your saving there. And what's not elegant about using delegates?

Comment: well i mean that's the only way i can see to do it, but it seems like a common thing to need to do stuff when something gets popped, so i assumed there was another way to do it.  there's nothing elegant about the code above haha it just seems like a "cheater" way to get the job done.  maybe its just me.

Comment: actually the method above doesn't even work.  So the problem stands.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem     *)item
{
  //insert your back button handling logic here
  // let the pop happen
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally do things like that in the "`viewWillDisappear:`" method of a view controller.

Yes it also will activate if you are going forward, but you can flag that to let the method know if you meant to launch something else - and it's probably a good idea to save no matter what at that point anyway...